# How to fix the broken divider of website to the bottom 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, wrapper

I am developing a website using react. I want to add a divider for all sections. But I can't set its position at bottom 0. It seems like this:
[image: divider]

I am using some wrappers. And maybe it's the reason.

[image]

[image]

I want to add a divider to the "work" section. Here are the files:

work.jsx:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AiFillEye, AiFillGithub } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { AppWrap, MotionWrap } from '../../wrapper';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';
import './Work.scss';


function Work() {

  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState('All');

  const [animateCard, setAnimateCard] = useState({ y:0, opacity: 1 });

  const [works, setWorks] = useState([]);
  const [filterWork, setFilterWork] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "works"]'
    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setWorks(data);
      setFilterWork(data);
    })
  }, [])
  

  const handleWorkFilter = (item) => {
    setActiveFilter(item);
    setAnimateCard([{ y:100, opacity:0 }])

    setTimeout (() => {
      setAnimateCard([{ y:0, opacity: 1}])
      
      if(item === 'All') {
        setFilterWork(works)
      } else {
        setFilterWork(works.filter((work) => work.tags.includes(item)))
      }
    },500)
  }





  return (
    <>

      <h2 className="head-text-green">MY PROJECTS</h2>

      <div className='app__work-filter'>
        {['UI/UX', 'REACT JS', 'HTML', 'JAVACRIPT', 'CSS', 'SCSS', 'ALL'].map((item, index) => 
          <div 
            className={`app__work-filter-item app__flex p-text-green ${activeFilter === item ? "item-active" : ""}`}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleWorkFilter(item)}
          >
            {item}
            
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <motion.div
        animate = {animateCard}
        transition = {{ duration: 0.5, delayChildren: 0.5 }}
        className = 'app__work-portfolio'
      >
        {filterWork.map((work, index) =>
          <div className='app__work-item app__flex' key={index}>
            <div className='app__work-img app__flex'>
              <img src={urlFor(work.imgUrl)} alt={work.name} />
              <motion.div
                whileHover={{ opacity: [0,1]}}
                transition={{ duration: 0.25, ease: 'easeInOut', staggerChildren: 0.5 }}
                className='app__work-hover app__flex'
              >
                <a href={work.projectLink} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
                  <motion.div
                    whileInView={{ scale: [0, 1]}}
                    whileHover={{ scale: [1, 0.9]}}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.25 }}
                    className='app__flex'
                  >
                    <AiFillEye />
                  </motion.div>
                </a>
                <a href={work.codeLink} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
                  <motion.div
                    whileInView={{ scale: [0, 1]}}
                    whileHover={{ scale: [1, 0.9]}}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.25 }}
                    className='app__flex'
                  >
                    <AiFillGithub />
                  </motion.div>
                </a>
              </motion.div>
            </div>

            <div className='app__work-content app__flex'>
              <h4 className='bold-text-green'>{work.title}</h4>
              <p className='p-text' style={{marginTop: 10}}>{work.description}</p>

              <div className='app__work-tag app__flex'>
                <p className='p-text'>{work.tags[0]}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        )}

      </motion.div>

      
      <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1657991521">
        <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path d="M602.45,3.86h0S572.9,116.24,281.94,120H923C632,116.24,602.45,3.86,602.45,3.86Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </>
  )
   
}


export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Work, 'app__works'),
  'work',
  'app__grey1bg'
);
```

work.scss:

```css
.app__works {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.app__work-filter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    margin: 4rem 0 2rem;

    .app__work-filter-item {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        background-color: #fff;
        
        font-weight: 800;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        margin: 0.5rem;

        &:hover {
            background-color: var(--secondary-color);
            color: #fff;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
            border-radius: 0.85rem;
        }
    }

    .item-active {
        background-color: var(--secondary-color);
        color: #fff;
    }
}

.app__work-portfolio {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    .app__work-item{
        width: 270px;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 2rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
            width: 470px;
            padding: 1.25rem;
            border-radius: 0.75rem;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 1rem;
        }
    }
}

.app__work-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    position: relative;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        height: 350px;
    }
}

.app__work-hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    div {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color: white;
        margin: 1rem;
        font-family: var(--font-base);
        font-weight: 800;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;

        svg {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            color: var(--white-color);
        }
    }
}

.app__work-content {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;

    h4 {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    .app__work-tag {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        top: -25px;
    }
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1657991521 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1657991521 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
    height: 58px;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1657991521 .shape-fill {
    fill: #BDD2B6;
}
```

appWrap.js (it use NavigationDots.jsx with classname="app__navigation" and SocialMedia.jsx with class name= "app__social" ):

```js
import { color } from '@mui/system';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationDots, SocialMedia } from '../components';

const AppWrap = (Component, idName, classNames) => function HOC() {
  return (
    <div id={idName} className={`app__container ${classNames}`}>
        <SocialMedia />

        <div className='app__wrapper app__flex'>
            <Component />

            <div className='copyright'>
                <p className='p-text'>@2022 AYGEN</p>
                <p className='p-text'>All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <NavigationDots active={idName} />


    </div>
    
  )
}

export default AppWrap;
```

MotionWrap.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const MotionWrap = (Component, classNames) => function HOC() {
  return (
    <motion.div
        whileInView={{ y: [100, 50, 0], opacity: [0, 0, 1] }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        className={`${classNames} app__flex`}
    >
        <Component />
    </motion.div>
  )
}

export default MotionWrap
```

a part of app.scss file:

```css
  .app__social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  
    padding: 1rem;

    position: initial;
  
    div {
      z-index: 5;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      
      
      
      margin: 0.25rem 0;
      border: 1px solid var(--lightGray-color);
  
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
  
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  
      svg {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        color: var(--green5-color);
      }
  
      &:hover {
        background-color: var(--secondary-color);
        border-color: var(--secondary-color);
  
        svg {
          color: var(--white-color);
        }
      }
  
      @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
  
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
  
        svg {
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
        }
      }

      

      
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        justify-content: center;
      
    }
  }
  
  .app__navigation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  
    padding: 1rem;
    
  
    .app__navigation-dot {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #cbcbcb;
      
      margin: 0.5rem;
  
      transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      z-index: 5;
  
      &:hover {
        background-color: var(--secondary-color);
      }
  
      @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
      }
      
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .app__navigation,
    .app__social {
      display: none;
    }
  
    .copyright {
      padding: 2rem;
    }
  }
```

I don't know if any other file is necessary to solve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because your `custom-shape-divider` element is inside `app__works div` and being positioned relative to it and not relative to `app__wrapper div`.

Comment: But where should I put the custom-shape-divider element then? I can't write in the next div in work.jsx, below </> tags, because it doesn't allow it. And should I change their position method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { color } from "@mui/system";
import React from "react";
import { NavigationDots, SocialMedia } from "../components";

const AppWrap = (Component, idName, classNames) =>
  function HOC() {
    return (
      <div id={idName} className={`app__container ${classNames}`}>
        <SocialMedia />

        <div className="app__wrapper app__flex">
          <Component />

          <div className="copyright">
            <p className="p-text">@2022 AYGEN</p>
            <p className="p-text">All rights reserved</p>
          </div>

          <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1657991521">
            <svg
              data-name="Layer 1"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
              preserveAspectRatio="none"
            >
              <path
                d="M602.45,3.86h0S572.9,116.24,281.94,120H923C632,116.24,602.45,3.86,602.45,3.86Z"
                class="shape-fill"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>

        <NavigationDots active={idName} />
      </div>
    );
  };

export default AppWrap;
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. In addition, this shows a divider on every page that uses app__wrapper. But what should I do if I don't want to show the divider on a specific page? I'll be glad if you also help me with this.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use `pathName` from `useLocation()` hook to check which current page you are and render your custom shape only for that page using a ternary operator